# Another approach for printing the website content using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

Currently I am using the method of  and config the css to print the file. However, I found this way is not feasible for my case as I am printing an e-book app image, which is difficult to modify the css code and print it. So ,

I am wondering if I create the new window, get the image link of the website and append it to that empty window  , and print the content, is it a good way to do this?

Also, is it possible to control the size of image print ? (currently if the screen size is smaller, the image print is smaller as well) . Thanks

Comment: I don't see how using a new window changes how you print.  If you need more control over printing than you get with CSS, I'm afraid you will have to use PDFs.

Comment: sorry . One last question... Can I set the print mode as landscape everytime when the print dialog is open? thanks

Comment: ok i get the answer already, thanks

Comment: Save your sanity. Go with PDFs. I command you. Bwahaha.